# Find the smallest $n$ such that $\frac{a^n}{n!} < \epsilon $

Tags: real-analysis

For $a>0$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$. I think the archimedean property of the reals tells us that for $n$ fixed, there exists some $\epsilon > 0$ such that the inequality is true. But how can you choose $n$ for fixed $\epsilon$?

Context: Trying to show that the sequence $\{ c_n = a^n/n! \}$ converges to zero, that is to say, for any fixed $\epsilon$, there's some $N$ such that $c_n < \epsilon$ for all $n \geq N$. How do find that $N$?

Edit: Another idea: Show that the sequence is Cauchy (so it must converge in $\mathbb{R}$); then suppose it converges to something other than 0; expose a contradiction.

Edit: Found another way to prove that the sequence (see Context) converges, so the question is void. (Just write $\{c_n\}$ as the product of $\{1,c_1,c_2,...\}$ and $\{a,a/2,a/3,...\}$; the former is bounded and the latter converges to 0, so the product rule for limits tells us that $c_n \rightarrow 0$.)

Comment: Why the smallest $n$ ?  This Question is posed largely in the title.  The body of the Question should give a complete statement of the problem, preferably with some context to indicate what methods have been tried and/or are available to apply.

Comment: we can provide some n but to prove whether it is optimal may be a bit tough

Comment: For proving that that the sequence converges, you don't have to find the smallest $n$

Comment: If you found a solution yourself, please post it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

From a purely algebraic point of view, consider the equation $$a^n=\epsilon \times n!$$ Take the logarithms of both sides and the equation becomes $$n\log(a)=\log(\epsilon)+\log(n!)$$ Now use Stirling approximation $$\log(n!)\approx \frac{1}{2}\log(2\pi)+(n+\frac{1}{2})\log(n)-n$$ so you have the equation to solve. Use any graphing tool and you are done.

For example, using $a=\frac{3}{4}$,$\epsilon=10^{-20}$ we find $n=19.3826$ while the exact solution is $n=19.3812$

Answer (score 1):

You won't get much further by using elementary ideas. The trick is to prove that the factorial grows faster than an exponential, and this is somehow hard. If you don't want to use Stirling, you can proceed as follows. Define
$$
p_n = \frac{a^n}{n!}
$$
and notice that
$$
\frac{p_{n+1}}{p_n} = \frac{a}{n}.
$$
Then
$$
p_{2} = a p_1, \quad p_3 = \frac{a}{2}p_2 = \frac{a}{2} a p_1 = \frac{a^2}{2}p_1,
$$
and similarly
$$
p_4 = \frac{a}{4}p_3 = \frac{a^3}{2^3}p_1, \ldots
$$
You should now guess that $p_n \approx 2^{-n+1}p_1$, and therefore $p_n \to 0$. This will not provide you with the *smallest* $n$ for a given $\varepsilon$, although you can get an *estimate*. But please remark that you don't need the smallest $n$, to prove that the limit is zero.